# C programming. Why does 'this' code work but not 'that' code?

Tags: c

Hello I am studying for a test for an intro to C programming class and yesterday I was trying to write this program to print out the even prime numbers between 2 and whatever number the user enters and I spent about 2 hours trying to write it properly and eventually I did it.  I have 2 pictures I uploaded below.  One of which displays the correct code and the correct output.  The other shows one of my first attempts at the problem which didn't work correctly, I went back and made it as similar to the working code as I could without directly copying and pasting everything.

unfortunately new users aren't allowed to post pictures hopefully these links below will work.

This fails, it doesn't print all numbers in range with natural square root:

```
for (i = 2; i <= x; i++)
{
   //non relevant line
   a = sqrt(i);
   aa = a * a;
   if (aa == i); 
       printf("%d ",i);
}
```

source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5wzj.jpg

While this succeeds, and prints even numbers with natural sqaure root

```
for (i = 2; i <= x; i++) 
{
   a = sqrt(i);
   aa = a * a;
   if (aa == i && ((i/2) *2) == i)
        printf("%d ", i);
}
```

source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufn6B.jpg

Hopefully you can see and read the screen shots I have here.  I know that the 'incorrect code' picture does not have the (i/2)*2 == i  part but I figured that it would still print just the odd and even numbers,  it also has the code to calculate "sqrd" but that shouldn't affect the output.  Please correct me if I'm wrong on that last part though.

And Yes I am using Dev-C++ which I've read is kinda crappy of a program but I initally did this on code::blocks and it did the same thing...

Please I would very much appreciate any advice or suggestions as to what I did wrong 2 hours prior to actually getting the darn code to work for me.

Thank you,
Adam

Comment: Please. PLEASE. Put your actual code into the question itself. How can anyone be expected to help you debug if we can't even copy / paste?

Comment: You don't need to post pictures, you can (and should) post the relevant code directly into your question.

Comment: the only even prime number is 2. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to post your code here; without it, your question is meaningless. Questions here should stand on their own, so that they remain meaningful to future readers. In addition, images of code are useless, as the code is hard to read and can't be copied and pasted into a code editor or IDE. Please edit your question to provide the code here as text, and we'll try and help you figure out what the problem is if we can. Thanks. :)

Comment: I added the relevant parts of the code to the question's body, hope I didn't have any significant typo - you are welcome to edit and fix it if I do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your code in 'that' includes:

```
if (aa == i);
//          ^
   printf(...);
```

[note the `;` at the end of the if condition]

Thus, if `aa == i` - an empty statement happens, and the print always occures, because it is out of the scope of the if statement.

To avoid this issue in the future, you might want to use explicit scoping<sup>1</sup> [using `{`, `}` after control flow statements] - at least during your first steps of programming the language.

---

1: spartan programmers will probably hate this statement

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input, especially amit.  And I apologize for posting a question with such a simple error,  I really should learn to read over my work better.  I've been at this for hours and my eyes must have just gotten too tired.  And I understand why you all say to post the actual 'text' code into my question and I will do that from now on.

Comment: @AdamJohnston: You shouldn't be sorry about a "question with simple error" - everyone always learns! I'm glad you understood that next time you should post the code itself - and not a picture of it. Also: You should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/161469) an answer that solves your issue.

Comment: Answer accepeted :D  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Such errors are common. I use "step Over", "Step Into", "Break Points" and "watch window" to debug my program. Using these options, you can execute your program line by line and keep track of the variables used in each line. This way, u'll know which line is not getting executed in the desired way.